# Javascript generated article identical to manual html but produces different results?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JQuery function that handles hiding and showing of a multiple divs on href push.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  //hide element 
  jQuery(".targetDiv").css("display", "none");
  // Hook the button click
    
  jQuery(".showEpisodes").click(function(e) {
  // To prevent reloading of page
  e.preventDefault(); 

  //toggle and hide all other div tags
  jQuery('#'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle('fast', function(){
    jQuery('.targetDiv').not($(this)).hide();

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="style1">
    <span class="image">
        <img src="">
    </span>
    <a href="#/" class="showEpisodes" target="1">
        <h2>Label</h2>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </a>
</article>
                
<div id="1" class="targetDiv">
    <ul>
        <li><button><span>1</span></button></li>
        <li><button><span>GitHub</span></button></li>
        <li><button><span>Phone</span></button></li>
        <li><button><span>Email</span></button></li>
        <li><button><span>StackOverflow</span></button></li>
        <li><button><span>StackOverflow</span></button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine, it's when i try to generate the articles with javascript using json to populate information in the tags that i run into trouble. Just to simplify it, i call a function:

```js
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
    for(var key in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
    }
}
    
function createArticleRow() {
    var sectionDiv = document.getElementById('videoElements');
            
    var art = document.createElement("article");
    art.setAttribute('class', 'style1');
    sectionDiv.appendChild(art);
    
    //for images
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute('class', 'image');
    
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute('src', 'coverUrl');
       
    art.appendChild(span);
    span.appendChild(image);
    
    var href = document.createElement("a");
    setAttributes(href, {"href": "#/", "class": "showEpisodes", "target": "1"});
    
    art.appendChild(href);
    
    var h2Tag = document.createElement("h2");
    h2Tag.innerHTML = 'title';
    href.appendChild(h2Tag);
    var divcont = document.createElement("div");
    divcont.setAttribute("class", "content");
    href.appendChild(divcont);
    var h3Tag = document.createElement("h3");
    h3Tag.innerHTML = 'description';
    divcont.appendChild(h3Tag);
}
function createDivRow(){
    var sectionDiv = document.getElementById('videoElements');
    var infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    setAttributes(infoDiv, {"id": 1, "class": "targetDiv"});
    // infoDiv.setAttribute("class", "hide");
    var trailerVideo = document.createElement("iframe");

    setAttributes(trailerVideo, {"width":420, "height": 315, "src": "embededTrailerLink"});
    infoDiv.appendChild(trailerVideo);
    sectionDiv.appendChild(infoDiv);
}

createArticleRow();
createDivRow();
jQuery(function() {
  //hide element 
  jQuery(".targetDiv").css("display", "none");
  // Hook the button click
    
  jQuery(".showEpisodes").click(function(e) {
  // To prevent reloading of page
  e.preventDefault(); 

  //toggle and hide all other div tags
  jQuery('#'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle('fast', function(){
    jQuery('.targetDiv').not($(this)).hide();

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="videoElements" class="tiles"></section>
```

For some reason this is working fine. But when I run this, the hrefs manually inputted work fine, but the generated html opens a new link with the same html page.

I feel like my problems have something to do with the href tag "#/" but i've tried many variations. I also thought that the might be some ordering issue with my import scripts.

I have opened up the elements console in a browser and the two are identical structurally, and both can access jquery.

Has anyone had similar experiences with this?

Comment: You have used `#` as href. It will redirect to same page.... What do actually want?

Comment: `generated html opens a new link with the same html page` wihtout any user interaction?

Comment: i thought appending to a html document from a javascript function would keep the same root tag #? I wanted the same behavior as the above snippets, with generated html and without opening a new root page and tab.